# Swift call Objective-C protocol readonly property

Tags: objective-c, protocols, swift2

I have a Objective-C protocol like this:

```
@protocol OBJCDelegate <NSObject> 
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *info;
- (void)setInfo:(NSString *)info;
@end

@interface OBJCObject: NSObject <OBJCDelegate>
@end
```

> The Objective-C code is from 3rd party library, i have no permission to modify it.

then i use swift2.0 call objective-c:

```
let objcObject = OBJCObject()
objcObject.setInfo("info") // error on this line, error is : Value of type 'OBJCObject' has no member 'setInfo'
```

swift cannot find the setInfo function, why?

Comment: What is the exact wording of the error?

Comment: @Tommy Value of type 'OBJCObject' has no member 'setInfo'

Comment: I'll try to set up a test project to reproduce; does the same issue exist if you do something like `let objcDelegate = objcObject as! OBJCDelegate` and then `objcDelegate.setInfo("info")`? Is the compiler denying that it conforms to `OBJCDelegate` or denying that `OBJCDelegate` provides `-setInfo:`?

Comment: How about `objcObject.info = "info"`?

Comment: Oh, yeah, possibly the bridge is smart enough to spot that `readonly` + `setInfo:` = a read/write property. Kudos to @trojanfoe!

Comment: Yeah the declaration is broken and that property should not be `readonly` (and `setInfo:` should be dropped).

Comment: The 3rd party author wrote some bad code there. Why would someone make a property read-only and provide an explicit setter method? That makes no sense at all.

Comment: Can you name which 3rd party you are using?